# how to download all the python packages mentioned in the requirement.txt to a folder in linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip

I want to download all the python packages mentioned in the requirement.txt to a folder in Linux. I don't want to install them. I just need to download them.

python version is 3.6

list of packages in the requirement.txt

```
aiodns==0.3.2
aiohttp==1.1.5
amqp==1.4.7
anyjson==0.3.3
astroid==1.3.2
asyncio==3.4.3
asyncio-redis==0.14.1
billiard==3.3.0.20
blist==1.3.6
boto==2.38.0
celery==3.1
pexpect==4.0
pycryptodomex==3.7.0
pycurl==7.19.5.1
pyinotify==0.9.6
pylint==1.4.0
pyminifier==2.1
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
pypacker==2.9
pyquery==1.2.9
pysmi==0.3.2
pysnmp==4.4.4
PyStaticConfiguration==0.9.0
python-daemon==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-ldap==3.2.0
python-libnmap==0.6.2
python-otrs==0.4.3
pytz==2015.4
PyYAML==3.11
query-string==0.0.2
queuelib==1.2.2
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.22.1
requests-aws4auth==0.9
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
requests-toolbelt==0.5.0
scp==0.10.2
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.1
tlslite==0.4.9
u-msgpack-python==2.1
urllib3==1.14
w3lib==1.12.0
websockets==3.3
Werkzeug==0.10.4
xlrd==1.0.0
XlsxWriter==1.0.5
zope.interface==4.1.2
GitPython==2.1.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation gives what you want : pip download

> pip download does the same resolution and downloading as pip install,
> but instead of installing the dependencies, it collects the downloaded
> distributions into the directory provided

[source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/)

So you may try these option with pip download :

```
pip download -r requirement.txt -d your_directory
```